# How to set bounds Graphics when using Metafile?

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, metafile, .emf

In our application it's possible to create images in different fileformats, like PNG, BMP, JPEG etc.
Now I'm currently investigating the possibility to create Metafile images (.emf).
With our Charts I can get this to work, because we're using the microsoft Charting library and with this it's possible to export a chart in .emf format.

> (ChartImageFormat.EmfDual);

We also create maps, and this is where it goes wrong. When I create the graphics using a Bitmap, the graphic element has a useful visibleClipbounds.

```
var image = new Bitmap(Width, Height);

using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
{
 //visibleClipbounds: {X = 0 Y = 0 Width = 1241 Height = 774}
}
```

When I use a metafile to create the graphics object, the VisibleClipbounds is enormous...

```
Graphics refG = Graphics.FromHwndInternal(IntPtr.Zero);
IntPtr refGrap = refG.GetHdc();
Metafile m = new Metafile(refGrap, EmfType.EmfPlusDual, "...");
using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(m))
{
//visibleClipbounds: {X = -4194304 Y = -4194304 Width = 8388608 Height = 8388608}
}
```

Is there a way I can create a graphics element using the metafile, but keep the visibleClipbounds the same way as when I create a graphics element using a Bitmap?

Comment: The point of a Metafile is to *not* have a fixed size.  Meant to be freely scalable, the essential difference between vector graphics and bitmap graphics.  Be sure to never use Graphics.DrawImage(), that defeats the point of using a Metafile.  Nevertheless, when you generate an EMF then you should include a size *recommendation*.  Use a constructor overload that accepts a RectangleF.